# can anyone tell me what the encoding of this string is? Its meant to be base64

Tags: base64

> cpxSR2bnPUihaNxIFFA8Sc+8gUnWuJxJi8ywSW5ju0npWrFJHW2MSZAeMklcZ71IjrBySF2ci0gdecRI0vD/SM4ZF0m1ZSJJBY8bSZJl/0intaxIlQJBSPdY3EdBLM9Hp4wLSOK8Nki8L1pIoglxSAvNbkjHg0VIDlv7R6B2Y0elCqVGFWuVRgagAkdxHTdHELxRR9i2VkdyEUlHU84kRzTS2kalKFxG

This is a string from an XML file from my mass spectrometer. I am trying to write a program to load two such files, subtract one set of values from another, and write the results to a new file. According to [the specification file for the .mzML format](http://www.psidev.info/mzml_1_0_0), the encoding of the numerical data is alleged to be [base64](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#base64Binary). I can't convert this data string to anything legible using any of the many online base64 converter or using NotepaD++ and the MIME toolkit's base64 converter.

The string, in the context of the results file, looks like this:

```
     <binaryDataArray encodedLength="224">
        <cvParam cvRef="MS" accession="MS:1000515" name="intensity array" unitAccession="MS:1000131" unitName="number of counts" unitCvRef="MS"/>
        <cvParam cvRef="MS" accession="MS:1000521" name="32-bit float" />
        <cvParam cvRef="MS" accession="MS:1000576" name="no compression" />
            <binary>cpxSR2bnPUihaNxIFFA8Sc+8gUnWuJxJi8ywSW5ju0npWrFJHW2MSZAeMklcZ71IjrBySF2ci0gdecRI0vD/SM4ZF0m1ZSJJBY8bSZJl/0intaxIlQJBSPdY3EdBLM9Hp4wLSOK8Nki8L1pIoglxSAvNbkjHg0VIDlv7R6B2Y0elCqVGFWuVRgagAkdxHTdHELxRR9i2VkdyEUlHU84kRzTS2kalKFxG</binary>
```

I can't proceed until I can work out what format this encoding is meant to be!

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: It's valid Base64. You're correct. As the spec says, it's 224 bytes of base64 encoded 32-bit floats with no compression.

Comment: Wow, ,thanks for the fast reply. Do you know how I can convert it into plaintext? It should convert to a list of floats.

Comment: I am completely guessing here, but I think you should read an array of 4-byte floats after de-base64ing the string.

Comment: It is not plain text.  They are 32-bit floats in binary.  You can write a program to print the values in any programming language that has the notion of a 32-bit floating point value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this trivial program to convert it to plaintext:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    float f;
    while (fread(&f, 1, 4, stdin) == 4)
        printf("%f\n", f);
}
```

I compiled this to "floatdecode" and used this command:

```
echo "cpxSR2bnPUihaNxIFFA8Sc+8gUnWuJxJi8ywSW5ju0npWrFJHW2MSZAeMklcZ71IjrBySF2ci0gdecRI0vD/SM4ZF0m1ZSJJBY8bSZJl/0intaxIlQJBSPdY3EdBLM9Hp4wLSOK8Nki8L1pIoglxSAvNbkjHg0VIDlv7R6B2Y0elCqVGFWuVRgagAkdxHTdHELxRR9i2VkdyEUlHU84kRzTS2kalKFxG" | base64 -d | ./floatdecode
```

Output is:

```
53916.445312
194461.593750
451397.031250
771329.250000
1062809.875000
1283866.750000
1448337.375000
1535085.750000
1452893.125000
1150371.625000
729577.000000
387898.875000
248514.218750
285922.906250
402376.906250
524166.562500
618908.875000
665179.312500
637168.312500
523052.562500
353709.218750
197642.328125
112817.929688
106072.507812
142898.609375
187123.531250
223422.937500
246822.531250
244532.171875
202255.109375
128694.109375
58230.625000
21125.322266
19125.541016
33440.023438
46877.441406
53692.062500
54966.843750
51473.445312
42190.324219
28009.101562
14090.161133
```

Comment: +1 for very nice code and the reading of the data from `echo`.  Nicely done.

Comment: I did the same in java but i am getting different results: http://ideone.com/6xxQ75 Don't get why

Comment: @guido: I assumed little-endian byte order because that gave data that seems sensible (no huge variations in magnitude and sign). Your code assumes big-endian byte order.

Comment: Thank you, everyone, and especially David for your solution. I intend to write this into my Processing program so I don't think I can use David's code but you have taught me how to translate my data. Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Yet another Java Base64 decode with options to uncompress should you need it](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/).
Vendor spec indicated "32-bit float" = IEEE-754 and specified little-endian.
[Schmidt's converter](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) shows the bit pattern for IEEE-754.

One more Notepad++ step to look at the hex codes:

> Notepad++ TextFX plugin (after the Base64 decode you already did)
>   select the text
>   TextFX > TextFX Convert > Convert text to Hex-32

lets you look at the hex codes:

> "000000000  72 9C 52 47 66 E7 3D 48- ...  6E 63 BB 49   |rœRGfç=H¡hÜHP

Little-endian: 47529C72 converts (via Schmidt) as shown above by David.

Answer (score 0):

You can access such data from mzML files in **Python** through **pymzML**, a python interface to mzML files.

http://pymzml.github.com/